# R, error in kmodes() application to a text matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to apply the [kmodes clustering](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/klaR/docs/print.kmodes) method (from klaR package) in R to a text matrix made of around 1000 strings and 6 columns.
Unfortunately, I get an error that I cannot comprehend:

```
kmodes(mat, 5, iter.max=10)
Error in cluster[j] <- which.min(dist) : replacement has length zero
```

Do you have any ideas about why this is happening?

EDIT: This is the head(mat):

```
1       aaa      ccc         iii         <NA>             0
2       aaa      ddd         kkk         <NA>             0
3       aaa      eee        -273         <NA>             0
4       aaa      fff         lll         <NA>             0
5       bbb      ggg          67         <NA>             0
6       bbb      hhh         mmm         <NA>             0
```

Comment: Just guessing here, somewhere we need to set `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I got: `unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Could you share the data or at least `head(mat)` ?

Comment: Any chance that column is all `<NA>`? Try removing all `NA` values manually before running the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well use `kmodes(na.omit(mat), 5, iter.max = 10)`, but that will lead to loss of data which is not appreciable. 
You could instead check the `summary(mat)` to find for missing data or NA values and then replace them using random imputation.

```
dataframeName$variable <- with(dataframeName, impute(variable, 'random'))
```

and in case you have too many NA values in a column/variable then you can also neglect that column.
Check out the link:-
https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/how-to-handle-missing-values-of-categorical-variables/310

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It seems to be due to missing data. Remove missing data from the data first, e.g. by using `kmodes(na.omit(mat), 5, iter.max=10)`.